# Suggestion on how to implement cross domain ajax call using old version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, version

Do all, the least jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
have the attribute called: "crossDomain", it works great for me to do some crossDomain AJAX call, but I got a problem....
If my client using some old school jQuery lib, which is no "crossDomain" attribute, any ideas on how to implement call using an old fashion way to do such a ajax call? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "attribute". Have you got an example of crossDomain in action?

Comment: $j.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
       url: aURL,
    data: aData,  
    crossDomain: true,  
    success: aSuccessCallBack, 
    error:function(status){ 
     alert("error"+status);
      }});

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, and you are trying to make an ajax post back to a domain different to your point of origin, then you could do this via proxy using the  ".load" or ".ajax" commands and creating a server side scraper to get the remote page for you. Here's how you'd do it in C#;

http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/simple-c-screen-scraping-proxy-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If the client has a server with PHP and `allow_url_fopen` set to true, you can make requests transit through a script which will return content of any url on another domain.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "crossdomain ajax" you actually could mean two different things - CORS-enabled XMLHttpRequest, and there is nothing much to do with jquery here - it is actually browser issue, Opera is the last "big" browser that doesn't support CORS-calls.

The second option is jsonp and jsonp is supported in jquery long ago.
It technically not an ajax (XMLHttpRequest) call, but generally speaking, it is the only option for you.